In this case does convergence of marginal distribution imply joint convergence in distribution
If $(S_n)_{n\geq 1}$, $A$ and $B$ (here we assume $A$ and $B$ are defined on the same probability space) are well-defined random variables, and $f$ and $g$ are two measurable functions. Then if we have $f(S_n)\overset{(d)}{\rightarrow} A$ and $g(S_n)\overset{(d)}{\rightarrow} B$, do we have $(f(S_n),g(S_n))\overset{(d)}{\rightarrow} (A,B)$? Where $(d)$ means convergence in distibution. I know in general convergence of marginal distribution doesn't imply joint convergence in distribution, however, I am wondering if joint convergence hold in this case, since both random variables are a function of a common random variable.
Further question (unsolved): To further clarify my question, if we here add an extra assumption that $S_n$ also converge in distribution to $S$, than shall we have the joint covergence in distribution? I think yes, since by definition, for every bounded measurable function $\phi: \mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have $\int \phi(f(x), g(x))\mathbb{P}_{S_n}(dx)\rightarrow \int \phi(f(x), g(x))\mathbb{P}_{S}(dx)$, since law of $S_n$ converges. However, by the answer provided below, it seems wrong on the other hand. Can someone maybe point out my mistake please?

"convergence to $(A, B)$" is not well-defined here since you haven't defined the joint distribution of $(A,B)$.

@angryavian Thank you. Sorry I am new to the topic, can you maybe point out how I could fix the problem? And I have updated my post :）

Clearly no. Consider $(S_n)_{n\geq 1} = (Z_n)_{n \geq 1}$ where $Z_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, a standard normal. Let $Z$ also denote a generic standard normal random variable. Consider $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$, then we have $f(S_n)\overset{D}{\to} Z$ and $g(S_n)\overset{D}{\to} Z$ since $\Phi$ (the pdf of $Z$) is symmetric.
However, this doesn't imply $(f(S_n), g(S_n))\overset{D}{\to} (Z, Z)$, since otherwise, by continuous mapping theorem, we will have $f(S_n)+g(S_n)\overset{D}{\to} Z + Z = 2Z$, which is not true as we know that $f(S_n)+g(S_n)=0$.

Thank you for your answer, however, I have doubts left and I put it in the 'Further question' section of my updated post

@RandomHarry If you really look into my answer, you'll find out that $(S_n){n\geq 1}$ doesn't change with $n$, it's just $Z$ throughout. Hence, from your reasoning, i.e., the integral converge, it means nothing in my provided example since you're saying $\int \phi(f, g),\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}{S_n}\to \int \phi(f, g),\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}_{S}$, and here we have $S_n = S = Z$. Think about what you're really trying to prove here.
